# Почему не выводится карта в диалоге?

Tags: c++, qt, map, qml

У меня программа зависает когда я пытаюсь вывести окно qml.
ArcGis я установил. Как вывести окно карт? Копировал код с [этого репозитория](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-qt/tree/master/ArcGISRuntimeSDKQt_CppSamples/Maps/DisplayMap)

Мой код:

addmodeldialog.cpp

```
void addModelDialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    DisplayMap::init();

    // Initialize application view
    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    // Add the import Path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("qml"));

    QString arcGISRuntimeImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_RUNTIME_IMPORT_PATH);
    QString arcGISToolkitImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_TOOLKIT_IMPORT_PATH);

#if defined(LINUX_PLATFORM_REPLACEMENT)
    // on some linux platforms the string 'linux' is replaced with 1
    // fix the replacement paths which were created
    QString replaceString = QUOTE(LINUX_PLATFORM_REPLACEMENT);
    arcGISRuntimeImportPath = arcGISRuntimeImportPath.replace(replaceString, "linux", Qt::CaseSensitive);
    arcGISToolkitImportPath = arcGISToolkitImportPath.replace(replaceString, "linux", Qt::CaseSensitive);
#endif

    // Add the Runtime and Extras path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISRuntimeImportPath);
    // Add the Toolkit path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISToolkitImportPath);

    // Set the source
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Samples/Analysis/ViewshedGeoElement/DisplayMap.qml"));
    view.show();
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&view);

    QDialog dialog;
    QHBoxLayout layout;

    dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    layout.addWidget(container);
    dialog.setLayout(&layout);
    dialog.show();
}
```

DisplayMap.h

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_MAP_H
#define DISPLAY_MAP_H

namespace Esri
{
  namespace ArcGISRuntime
  {
    class Map;
    class MapQuickView;
  }
}

#include <QQuickItem>

class DisplayMap : public QQuickItem
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit DisplayMap(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);
  ~DisplayMap();

  void componentComplete() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  static void init();

private:
  Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Map* m_map = nullptr;
  Esri::ArcGISRuntime::MapQuickView* m_mapView = nullptr;
};

#endif // DISPLAY_MAP_H
```

DisplayMap.cpp

```
#include "DisplayMap.h"

#include "Map.h"
#include "MapQuickView.h"
#include "Basemap.h"

using namespace Esri::ArcGISRuntime;

DisplayMap::DisplayMap(QQuickItem* parent) :
  QQuickItem(parent)
{
}

DisplayMap::~DisplayMap() = default;

void DisplayMap::init()
{
  qmlRegisterType<MapQuickView>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "MapView");
  qmlRegisterType<DisplayMap>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "DisplayMapSample");
}

void DisplayMap::componentComplete()
{
  QQuickItem::componentComplete();

  //! [MapQuickView API Snippet]
  // find QML MapView component
  m_mapView = findChild<MapQuickView*>("mapView");

  // create a new basemap instance
  Basemap* basemap = Basemap::imageryWithLabels(this);
  // create a new map instance
  m_map = new Map(basemap, this);
  // set map on the map view
  m_mapView->setMap(m_map);
  //! [MapQuickView API Snippet]
}
```

DisplayMap.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Esri.Samples 1.0
import Esri.ArcGISExtras 1.1

DisplayMapSample {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    //! [add a mapView component]
    MapView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "mapView"
    }
    //! [add a mapView component]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на тельце вот этого метода-слота:

```
void addModelDialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    DisplayMap::init();

    //...

    // Initialize application view
    QQuickView view;

    // ...
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&view);

    QDialog dialog;
    //...
    dialog.show();
}
```

Все эти объекты создаются в стековой (локальной) памяти метода и как только метод завершает свою работу эти объекты уничтожаются (в том числе container потому что его `parent` "тянет" его за собой). Поэтому у вас все зависает.

В репозитории, вы скопировали этот код из метода main.cpp, который создает локальную переменную приложения `a` с главным циклом событий программы `a.exec()`, завершение работы которого происходит при получении соответствующего сообщения, поэтому там этот код работает.

1. Чтобы заработало как надо, надо вместо вызова `dialog.show()` сделать вызов `dialog.exec()`, которое не завершит свою работу пока пользователь явно не закроет диалоговое окно.

**Уточнение**. Если вы оставите вызов `dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`, то работать не будет. Поменяйте эту строчку на такую `dialog.setWindowFlags( dialog.windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`

**Уточнение 2** надо убрать `view.show()`. Вот что написано в документации:

> Creating a native window for the window container also allows for
>   proper stacking and clipping. This must be done before showing the
>   window container
>
> перевод: Создание окна для оконного контейнера приводит к правильному
>   конструированию стека и обрезке (окна). Это должно быть выполнено до
>   того как будет показан (show) оконный контейнер

2. Либо создать локальный цикл сообытий при помощи класса `QEventLoop`.

Comment: Спасибо .... сейчас исправлю исключение и проверю

Comment: заменил .show() на .exec() не помогло .....появляется и пропадает диалог

Comment: @IvanTriumphov это из-за этой строчки `dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`

Comment: @IvanTriumphov дополнил ответ

Comment: Всё равно появляется и исчезает

Comment: @IvanTriumphov а если вообще убрать эти две строчки?

Comment: Тогда появляется окно но не выводиться карта

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91706/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-ivan-triumphov).

Answer (score 1):

У меня получился такой код :

```
void addModelDialog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
    {
        DisplayMap::init();

        // Initialize application view
        QQuickView view;
        view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

        // Add the import Path
        view.engine()->addImportPath(QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("qml"));

        QString arcGISRuntimeImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_RUNTIME_IMPORT_PATH);
        QString arcGISToolkitImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_TOOLKIT_IMPORT_PATH);

        // Add the Runtime and Extras path
        view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISRuntimeImportPath);
        // Add the Toolkit path
        view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISToolkitImportPath);

        // Set the source
        view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Samples/Analysis/ViewshedGeoElement/DisplayMap.qml"));

        QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&view);

        QDialog dialog;
        QHBoxLayout layout;
        layout.addWidget(container);
        setMinimumSize(800,800);
        dialog.setLayout(&layout);
        dialog.exec();
        QEventLoop loop;
        loop.exec();
    }
```

Comment: А если поменять dialog.exec() на dialog.show()?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin  тоже срабатывает